# Fetching columns from three tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch three different columns from three tables(table1,table2 and table3) and the user_id is a reference. Help me for the query in mysql php

Comment: use joins while trying to fetch

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html try reading this

Comment: add some sample query and output details

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`...You can use multiple tables in your single SQL query. The act of joining in MySQL refers to smashing two or more tables into a single table.

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.user_id = table3.user_id
```

You can use JOINS in SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to join MySQL tables. We will see an example of LEFT JOIN also which is different from simple MySQL JOIN.

[Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN query for this.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as ti1,table2 as ti2,table3 as ti3 WHERE ti1.user_id = ti2.user_id AND ti1.user_id=ti3.user_id
```